# Determining the last entry date on a journey via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I'm trying to analyze our running journeys automatically and would like to retrieve the information when was the last time someone entered a given journey. No identifiable information is necessary - just when was the last time the event fired someone into a journey.

Does anyone know if we can find information like this anywhere within MC?

---

The endpoint `GET interaction/v1/interactions/key:{key}` would be the obvious choice, but from it we can only learn what were the creation, modification and publish dates.

I tried to find the last entry date within three other endpoints retrieved from the [Interaction REST Discovery Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/restDiscovery.htm):

**1. GET interaction/v1/getTriggerStatistics/{eventDefinitionID}**

```
"getTriggerStatistics": {
    "path": "triggerstats/{eventDefinitionID}",
    "httpMethod": "get",
    "description": "Retrieve trigger statistics",
    "parameters": {
        "eventDefinitionID": "Event definition Id"
    }
}
```

This can be useful for volumes entering a journey, but does not contain any information about dates.

---

**2. GET interactions/v1/history**

```
"getHistory": {
    "path": "history",
    "httpMethod": "get",
    "description": "Retrieve a collection of history.",
    "parameters": {}
}
```

This is an OK, call, but it actually does not return anything of value:

```
{
"count": 0,
"page": 1,
"pageSize": 50,
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/v1/history"
        }
    },
    "items": []
}
```

---

**3. GET  interactions/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/download**

```
"downloadJourneyHistoryGet": {
    "path": "interactions/journeyhistory/download",
    "httpMethod": "get",
    "description": "Download Journey history",
    "parameters": {}
}
```

This one straight up returns a `500 Internal Server Error`, but returns an interesting message with the error 400  if I remove the last `/download` route:

```
{
    "message": "Must provide a valid ID or Key parameter",
    "errorcode": 10005,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

Any attempts to include the id or key failed (Status 404):

```
- interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/{id}
- interaction/v1/interactions/{id}/journeyhistory
- interaction/v1/interactions/{id}/journeyhistory/download
- interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/key:{key}
- interaction/v1/interactions/key:{key}/journeyhistory
- interaction/v1/interactions/key:{key}/journeyhistory/download
```

---

Does anyone know if there's some endpoint that could have this information?

Comment: I use the `journeyhistory/search` endpoint to get and log jb events, check out this article by Rachid: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/27/get-journey-history-by-filtering-the-definition-id-via-api/

Comment: @zuzannamj thank you kindly for posting this - It's even better than what I needed. With the help of those logs I was able to sort the results by a descending `CreatedDate` and finding the first record with `"activityType": "Trigger"` which contains the information I'm looking for.

Comment: My pleasure Rafal :-)

Comment: @zuzannamj Would you mind posting your comment as an answer? This way we could close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the last 30 days of journey history    from `POST /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search`.

You will need to use the journey definition id in the payload:

```
{

    "definitionIds": [

        "06d6f3f6-4532-4fb3-908c-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

    ],

    "start": "2019-10-23T12:29:11.882Z",

    "end": null,

    "extras": "all"

}
```

Read more here: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/27/get-journey-history-by-filtering-the-definition-id-via-api/